# Is it possible to add additional logic to the parse.com backend?

Tags: parse-platform

I want to create a network card game app that uses parse.com to keep track of users and user scores. Is it possible to add some of the game logic to the parse.com backend / server? Or would you have to set up an additional server? The server would need to match up players and have the logic to determine winners.

Comment: Check out Parse's Cloud Code

Answer (score 2):

Cloud code is the answer.

You can create cloud functions that interact with your client side application through Parse's convenient PFCLoud interface. The cloud code interface is in Javascript, and the main way to access it is usually to install the Parse toolkit and you use `parse deploy` to upload your code to Parse's servers. For more information, see the cloud code guide at parse.com, linked below.

```
https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @lpapp question was very general and lack the proper investigation/efforts of something being done prior to the question.. wouldn't this question just answer what he needed... to go and check documentation in first place?

Comment: @Chasky this answer was a link-only non-answer originally; that's what lpapp was complaining about. Now it's edited – see its revision history.